# Direction vectors and cross product

Tags: vectors

I need some help with a quick question that I'm doing on an online math course regarding vectors. The question is:

Based on the diagram in Question 1 or your previous answers, determine the cross product CA × BD. If CA × BD = xi + yj + zk, what is the value of z?

Both CA and BD are direction vectors. So they have an arrow to the right above both of them. so the vector from C TO A, and from B TO D. I've calculated them below.

CA is <1.5, 2.5, 3> and BD is <3, -4, 0>

The question confuses me as it asks for the cross product, or so I think, but then it uses multiplication.

Can someone help me work it out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiplication to calculate a cross product. In fact, in total, you need 6 multiplications and 3 subtractions.

You are only asked to compute the z-component of the cross product; this requires two multiplications and one subtraction.

Look harder at the formula for a cross prodcut.